# Android Google Maps API: Hide Marker Snippet

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the Google Maps API v2 and am trying to embed a reference ID to a marker info window.  When a user clicks on the info window, it should pass the reference ID to a new intent.

I don't actually want the reference ID to be visible to the user.  I added the reference ID as a snippet and use marker.getSnippet() to get the reference ID to pass to the new activity.  Is there a way to hide the snippet so the user doesn't see it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Customize the info window contents via an `InfoWindowAdapter`, attached it to your `GoogleMap` via `setInfoWindowAdapter()`. Implement `onInfoContents()` on the adapter to return something that does not contain your snippet.

Comment: To achieve this I used this answer :) thanks for the idea

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17549438/1339326

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing and found something interesting myself.
The trick might seem so dumb but it worked perfect.
After getting the value from the **Snippet** in **onMarkerClick(Marker m)** I'm setting it back to null :D
Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    locationMarker = marker;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MarkerInfoView.class);
    String uid = marker.getSnippet();
    marker.setSnippet("");
    intent.putExtra(UID,uid);
    startActivity(intent);
    return false;
}
```

So, on **onClick()** it shows the title and opens another activity and shows the related other information of the user there.
Give me crazy thumbzzup if it works for you ;) 
Let me know if anyone need other coding help on tracking user and marker click operations.I'll try yo help as much as possible.
Good Luck (y)

Screenshot here:
[image]