# How to get click event of the marker text

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am displaying google map api v2 in my app. I have set some markers in the map.
I have also set title and snippet on the markers which are shown when you click the marker.

Now I want to call a new activity when clicked on the marker's title and not on marker itself.

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListner
```

is called only on the click of the marker.

But I dont want to do that. I want the marker to show the title and snippet on the click of the marker but I want to call new activity on the click of the title.

Any idea how we do that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Marker Click Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455815/android-marker-click-function)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To achieve this you need to implement `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` in your `getInfoContents` method so that a click on your `infoContents` window will wake the listener to do what you want, you do it like so:

```
   map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(args.getTitle());

                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                        if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                        {   
                            if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                    String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                                tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                                for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                                {
                                    String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                    String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                    if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                    {  
                                        task = tmptask;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }
        });
```

Comment: Heloo emil Adz ,
hw cn i Transfer the detail of marker to the new Activity by clicking on that marker please any body can help me on that

Comment: @NikhilSingh, it has nothing to do with the question at hand, but to do that you can pass this data to the next activity by adding it to the intent bundle that you created to open the next activity.

Comment: @EmilAdz thanks sir fr ur response bt how i can get the information of only that marker on which it is clicked

Comment: @NikhilSingh, I don't understand you question, you do it exactly as it shown here in the answer. Please ask a new and more clear question and I will try to help you there.

Comment: @EmilAdz it seems like it handles clicking event for the whole **InfoWindow**, how about if my window view have 2 **TextView** and 1 **Button** then I wanna handle clicking event for *only* the **Button**?

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce, you can't do it.

Answer (score 23):

To set a title on a marker:

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

To set a click listener on title:

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: where is that method in the second code snippet supposed to be placed? I'm just putting it in the Activity Class and it keeps telling me 'cannot resolved symbol 'setOnInfoWindowClickListener''

Comment: Hi @PatMyron, I am not sure, why you are getting this. Did you import the listener? And where exactly are you placing your code?

Comment: You need to import the listener.

Answer (score 8):

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;  
mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
                        String reference = mMarkerPlaceLink.get(arg0.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("reference", reference);

                        // Starting the  Activity
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Log.d("mGoogleMap1", "Activity_Calling");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * adding individual markers, displaying text on on marker click on a
 * bubble, action of on marker bubble click
 */
private final void addLocationsToMap() {
    int i = 0;
    for (Stores store : storeList) {
        LatLng l = new LatLng(store.getLatitude(), store.getLongtitude());

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(l)
                .title(store.getStoreName())
                .snippet("" + i)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        ++i;
    }

    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            try {
                popUpWindow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Stores store = storeList.get(Integer.parseInt(marker
                        .getSnippet()));

                // set details
                email.setText(store.getEmail());
                phoneNo.setText(store.getPhone());
                address.setText(store.getAddress());

                // setting test value to phone number
                tempString = store.getPhone();
                SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
                spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0,
                        spanString.length(), 0);
                phoneNo.setText(spanString);

                // setting test value to email
                tempStringemail = store.getEmail();

                SpannableString spanString1 = new SpannableString(tempStringemail);
                spanString1.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString1.length(), 0);
                email.setText(spanString1);

                storeLat = store.getLatitude();
                storelng = store.getLongtitude();

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                Log.e("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", " Occured");
            }

        }
    });

}
```